# Big data storage with Geo, for frequent update

Tags: django, bigdata, geospatial, datastore

I have to choose a big data storage for my project

It has to include Geo (lat, lon and some computation based on that, like distance from specified location).

Data will be updated very often. Every minute I plan to update about 20k-80k objects. It will store about 500k objects in total. Every minute I'll be given a set of ~50k objects in XML. I need to parse it and update the existing ones plus add the new ones as well.

All objects will be unique, based on a specific field.
In some time I'll have to add storing historical data (each object 3 week back, updated every minute).

What storage do you suggest? I'm thinking about aws redis, or mongodb. I'm worried that ppstgresql won't make it.

My project is made in Django and processing will be triggered using Celery

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Accumulo](https://accumulo.apache.org/) with [GeoMesa](http://www.geomesa.org/) plugin.

This site helps you understand how to configure and use it. I tried it, when I was working on large spatial data and it worked great at the time.

I configured Accumulo using Cloudera stack because it made configuring Accumulo simple but you can install it independently.